# Does $\{(-1)^n\mid n\in\mathbb N\}=\{-1,1\}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, elementary-set-theory

In my course of topology, we distinguish sequence s.t. $\#\{x_n\mid n\in\mathbb N\}<\infty $ and sequence where $\#\{x_n\mid n\in\mathbb N\}=\infty $, and in particular, we have at a moment that $$\{x_n\mid n\in\mathbb N\}=\{(-1)^n\mid n\in\mathbb N\}=\{-1,1\}.$$
In a way I agree with the last equality, but I'm also very disturbed by it. Indeed, if we have two sets $A$ and $B$, then $$A=B\implies A'=B',$$
where $A'$ and $B'$ denote the limits point of $A$ and $B$ respectively. Now, if I set $$A=\{(-1)^n\mid n\in\mathbb N\}\quad \text{and}\quad B=\{-1,1\},$$
then $A'=\{-1,1\}$, whereas $B'=\emptyset$. So, how can be interpreted $$\{(-1)^n\mid n\in\mathbb N\}=\{-1,1\} \ \ \ ?$$

Comment: $A'$ is still the empty set. The confusing thing is that the limit points of a set given as a sequence using set builder notation and the limit points of the actual sequence can be different.

Comment: I miss something. The set $A$ is made of isolated points, so $A^{\prime}=\emptyset=B^{\prime}$, right?

Comment: @Ian : Oh, I see, thanks a lot. My confusion came from that fact that the limit point of $\{\frac{1}{n}\mid n\in\mathbb N\}'=\{0\}$, so I thought we just need a subsequence that converge to the point...

Comment: You do, but in the definition of limit point (at least the one you're using) the subsequence needs to consist entirely of distinct points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$1$ is not a limit point of $A=\left\{(-1)^n \;|\; n \in \mathbb{N}\right\}$ (however you write it) because for $1$ to be a limit point of $A$, every neighborhood of $1$ would have to contain a point of $A$ *distinct from $1$*.  This extra condition of the definition is important here.  (Alternately, it's necessary for there to be a sequence in $A \setminus \{1\}$ whose limit is $1$.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I in fact confused limit point of a sequence and limit point of the range of the sequence... (because for $(1/n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ they are the same)